# Popup Dialog in Tkinter/Python

Tags: python, popup, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I need to add a popup dialog box on my GUI. 
So, when ever I hover my mouse over a label, it should be able to show a popup( Like the type we get while hovering over a file in windows).
It should also disappear as soon i move away the mouse.

To start with, I am not even sure which module or class to use. I tried menu, but the results are not what i expected.
I also tried to learn tkCommonDialog, but couldn't understand it properly.
Please Advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The little popup window is called a [tooltip](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ToolTip).

Answer (score 1):

This post may be relevant:  http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/505848-tkinter-button-overrelief

Comment: the link you gave only changes the text of widget. Though even control is similar to what i need.
Here What i need is to show a popup(containing info abt the widget). The popup should appear and disapper the same way as given in the link.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Balloon widget in the Tix package. I think it is just what you are looking for.